# How to restrict access to a site in IIS using windows authentication but uses forms authentication with the site

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have an Asp.net site that uses forms authentication to login users. I want to deploy the site to my stage/qa environment and use windows authentication at the IIS level to restrict access to the site to just the people testing the site. 
Problem is, when I try this, the windows authentication test users, onced logged in,  automatically logs in the user to the Asp.net site.  How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Network Service account from the website folder and add the accounts or group that you want to give access.  Leave the application on Form auth.   This should require the user to have access to the website folder before it will attempt to authenticate with forms.